Amazon CodeGuru Profiler vs Async Profiler
Does Amazon CodeGuru Profiler use Async Profiler internally ? It doesn't seem so since it runs as a thread inside the application process and doesn't need sysctl settings. Does someone know what does it use under the hood ?
Used Amazon Code Profiler and async profiler
